# In ts I want a function's parameter to be of type string, but there can be several known strings as hints

Tags: typescript

```js
function fn(str: string | 'abc') {}

fn('a'); // I want to get the prompt for abc after typing a
```

[image]

I want to get the prompt for abc after typing a, what should I do.

Comment: `function fn(str: (string&{}) | 'abc') {}` . Your question is 100% a duplicate, however I can't find related question/answer. Maybe somebody can find the link

Comment: You're so fast, thanks.